# Is $Ext^1(A,B)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$ enough to show two indecomposable modules are isomorphic?

Tags: modules, exact-sequence

I want to show two $R$-mdoules $X,\,Y$ are isomorphic. I have shown both exist in the following short exact sequences,

$0\to B\to X\to A\to 0$ and $0\to B\to Y\to A\to 0$.

In other words, $X,\,Y\in Ext^1(A,\,B)$. I have also shown $Ext^1(A,\,B)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $X,\,Y$ are both indecomposable. Is this enough to deduce that $X\cong Y$ since they are both in the same nontrivial class of $Ext^1(A,\,B)$? Or do I need to construct an explicit homomorphism $\varphi:X\to Y$ such that their short exact sequences commute?

Answer (score 0):

$X,Y \in \operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ isn't what you mean.

If the two short exact sequences represent the same element of $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ then they are equivalent as short exact sequences, which means there are maps
$$ \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \to & B & \to & X & \to & A & \to & 0 \\
 & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \\
0 &\to & B & \to & Y & \to &A & \to & 0
\end{array}
$$
where the outer vertical maps are identities. By the five lemma the middle vertical map is an isomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean by "$X,Y\in Ext^1(A,B)$ isn't what you mean"?

Comment: It doesn't make sense.  Modules aren't elements of ext groups. You can't just omit the maps in the ses, because in general there will be inequivalent ses with the same middle term.

Comment: Okay, well what I mean is that they both exist in an exact sequence of the above form. So I suppose what I am asking is this: if $X,Y$ both exist in the above exact sequences, and I know $Ext^1(A,B)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2$ then (up to equivalence) there are only two exact sequences - the one that splits, and the one that doesn't. If $X,Y$ are both indecomposable, then surely this mean they belong to the same equivalence class and are hence isomorphic. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's ok. If $X$ is indec then $0 \to B \to X \to A \to 0$ can't be split, so it can't be zero in the ext group.  It's the converse that might fail in general (I think).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I suppose one could generalize this argument. If $X,Y$ belong to two equivalence classes that are mutually inverse, then wouldn't they still be isomorphic? Since, if $p:X\to A$ is the one map in equivalence class $c$ (say), then $-p:Y\to A$ would be the map in its inverse class $-c$. One could then induce isomorphisms at either end so you again get an isomorphism in the middle. Is that right?

Comment: it's true that the middle terms are iso for any two ses which are scalar multiples of one another by a unit in fact.

Comment: @m_t_ Could I clarify the last point you made. I have ended up looking at $Ext^1(A,B)\cong\mathbb{Z}/3$. I claim any middle terms that do not split as $A\oplus B$ must be isomorphic. Suppose $X, X^\prime$ are middle terms in the SES $0\to B\to ?\to A\to 0$ that do not split. If they belong to the same class $c_1$, then they are isomorphic. Alternatively, one belongs to $c_1$ (say $X$), the other to $-c_1$. This surely implies $X^\prime$ is the middle term in an exact sequence congruent to $-c_1$. As the middle term in $-c_1$ is $X$, it follows from the Five Lemma that $X\cong X^\prime$.